# SQL Faster check for finite number of ids in table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

```
/*
SET NOCOUNT ON 
CREATE TABLE #tmp(userId INT NOT NULL, productId INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT pk_Temp PRIMARY KEY(userid, productId))
DECLARE @u INT = 0
DECLARE @p INT = 0
WHILE @u < 100000
BEGIN
    SET @u = @u + 1
    WHILE @p < 29
    BEGIN

        SET @p = @p + 1
        IF RAND() * 100 < 99
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #tmp
            VALUES (@u, @p)     
        END 
    END 
    SET @p = 0
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF 
DROP TABLE #tmp
DROP INDEX ix_TempOne ON #tmp
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_TempOne ON #tmp (userId)
DROP INDEX ix_TempTwo ON #tmp
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_TempTwo ON #tmp (userId) INCLUDE(productId)
DROP INDEX ix_TempThree ON #tmp
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_TempThree ON #tmp (productId)
DROP INDEX ix_TempFour ON #tmp
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_TempFour ON #tmp (productId) INCLUDE (userId)
*/
begin transaction t1
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp2') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #tmp2        

DECLARE @date DATETIME = GETDATE()  
SELECT userId INTO #tmp2 FROM #tmp WHERE userId BETWEEN (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (100+1)+1)) AND (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (100000+1)+1))
SELECT DISTINCT productId FROM #tmp WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM #tmp2)
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(millisecond, @date, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + ' miliseconds' + CHAR(10)
```

This is an example and similar to one of our cache tables which we used to filter on.

Based on the resultset (set created at #tmp2) we want to know which ProductId still fit the filtered options.
(The random part is just added to make a dynamic result set)

Currently I have set a primary key on userId and productId and have index "TempTwo" and "TempFour" on my database but the query will often still result in 400-1000 milliseconds calls when I want it to be lower than 100 milliseconds.

Is there a way for me to change the concept of the table or change the way I collect my information to get the result within 100 milliseconds?

The table is a cache table which is only updated once every now.

Comment: Can you explain what the code is supposed to be doing?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: The code is showing what it is supposed to be doing, I just want it to do it faster